# liftweb SetHtml couldn't handle future object in ajaxsubmit

Tags: lift, futuretask

I want to show future response in UI in a liftweb framework.

Following is a `Loggable` snippet method(`processRequest`) I'm currently using *to respond back future object* to UI `textarea` using `SetHtml` but blocking with `Thread.sleep`

```
 27 def render = {

 45  def processRequest() : JsCmd = {                                                                
 46                                                                                                     
 47       val future_ : LAFuture[String] = new LAFuture()                                               
 48                                                                                                     
 49       val urlRequest = url(request)                                                                 
 51       val future = Http(urlRequest OK as.String)                                                                                                                                
 57                                                                                                     
 58       future onSuccess {                                                                            
 59               case json =>                                                                          
 60                 resp = json                                                                         
 61                 logger.info(s"[onSuccess] response => ${json}")                                     
 62                 SetHtml("response", Text(resp+"")) //FIXME                                          
 63                 logger.info(s"[onSuccess] response => ${json}") //works fine                                     
 64                                                                                                     
 65       }                                                                                             
 66                                                                                                     
 67       future onFailure {                                                                            
 68               case exception =>                                                                     
 69                 logger.info(s"${exception.getMessage()}")                                           
 70       }                                                                                             
 71       Thread.sleep(2000) //TEMPORARY FIX                                                                           
 72       logger.info("[outside] response => ${resp}")                                                  
 73       SetHtml("response", Text(resp))  //it works in blocking mode                                                             
 74   }            

 77     "@requestid"  #> text(requestid, s => requestid = s) &                                          
 78     "@request"    #> text(request  , s => request = s) &                                            
 79     "@response"   #> textarea(responseString, s=>responseString = s) &                                                                            
 81     "@processreq" #> ajaxSubmit("Send Request", processRequest) 
 75  }
```

`SetHtml` doesn't work inside `onSuccess`, though I get json there. `SetHtml` has [following doc](http://liftweb.net/api/25/api/net/liftweb/http/js/JsCmds%24%24SetHtml.html),

> Replaces the content of the node with the provided id with the markup
>   given by content
>
> This is analogous to assigning a new value to a DOM object's innerHtml
>   property in Javascript.

I have all this app available at [github.](https://github.com/iPrayag/moonmarket-sbt/blob/master/src/main/scala/code/snippet/HulakiController.scala)

What I want is solution to `SetHtml` in handling future object where the request itself is through ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SetHtml` returns a `JsCmd`, but in order for that to be sent to the browser it would need to be part of a server response. However, as you are calling it asynchronously there is no response to send it with and therefore the browser never receives it. To fix that you have two options:

1. Wait for the future to finish by blocking, something like having
   your function return `future.get`
2. Use an actor which allows for server push communication with the browser. In that way, your future could send a message to the actor upon completion and then the actor would send the `setHtml` command.

There is a quick example with Lift actors here (unfortunately uses the old bind syntax in render) which illustrates how to send a message and have that execute `setHtml`: https://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/liftweb/Comet_Support

Comment: I've achieved this using [CometListener](https://github.com/iPrayag/moonmarket-sbt/blob/master/src/main/scala/code/comet/HulakiListener.scala) and [ListenerManager](https://github.com/iPrayag/moonmarket-sbt/blob/master/src/main/scala/code/comet/HulakiListenerManager.scala) **but** need to fix UI stuffs using plain html instead of generating through lift. Need suggestion on that. Here's my [html](https://github.com/iPrayag/moonmarket-sbt/blob/master/src/main/webapp/hulaki/list.html) at the moment.

Comment: Almost everything in lift can be invoked as a tag, like `<lift:comet ...` or as a class, like: `<div class="lift:comet"...` or with an HTML5 data attribute, like: `<div data-lift="comet"...`. So, you can just replace this `<lift:comet type="HulakiListener" name="none"` in your code with something like: `<div data-lift="comet?type=HulakiListner&name=none">`. May need tweaking, but should get you started.